# crear función con un argumento como selector DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito crear una función con un argumento  que corresponda a un selector DOM, algo así como `función (argumento) {código ejecutable}; argumento = algún selector` como `querySelectorAll(".x")`

Tengo un código pero no hace nada.

```js
x = document.querySelectorAll(".primero");

function myFunction(x) {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".x");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2 class="encabezar">Este es un encabezado con la clase ="encabezar"</h2>
  <p class="primero">Primer párrafo con la clase ="primero"</p>
  <p class="segundo">Segundo párrafo con la clase ="segundo"</p>
  <p class="tercero">Tercer párrafo con la clase ="tercero"</p>


  <button onclick="myFunction()">Enviar</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si entendí bien buscas algo como esto

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  var z = document.querySelectorAll('.' + x);
  for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    z[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="encabezar">Este es un encabezado con la clase ="encabezar"</h2>
<p class="primero">Primer párrafo con la clase ="primero"</p>
<p class="segundo">Segundo párrafo con la clase ="segundo"</p>
<p class="tercero">Tercer párrafo con la clase ="tercero"</p>
<button onclick="myFunction('primero')">Enviar</button>
```

Recuerda que de acuerdo a las reglas de JavaScript las variables que declaras en closures interiores "ocultan" las de los closures exteriores pero no las sobreescriben

```js
var a = 10;

function fn() {
  var a = 20;
  console.log('interno', a);
}

fn();
console.log('externo', a);
```

Por eso hacer

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".primero");
function myFunction(x) {
```

se refiere a dos variables distintas.

Comment: Ahora sí. Necesitaba recuperar un elemento DOM para después incorporarlo como argumento a una función en javascript. Adjunto el código más arriba.

Comment: @RTLM-7 No te olvides de votar si te sirvió la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

No estás tan lejos, tan solo es tener en cuenta cuando y como acceder los parámetros del objeto:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {   
      x[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 class="encabezar">Este es un encabezado con la clase ="encabezar"</h2>
<p class="primero">Primer párrafo con la clase ="primero"</p> 
<p class="segundo">Segundo párrafo con la clase ="segundo"</p> 
<p class="tercero">Tercer párrafo con la clase ="tercero"</p> 


<button onclick="myFunction(document.querySelectorAll('.primero'))">Enviar</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var respuesta = document.getElementById("clase").value;
    colorear (respuesta);
}

function colorear(x)  {
    var z = document.querySelectorAll('.' + x);
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {   
    z[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 class="encabezar">Este es un encabezado con la clase ="encabezar"</h2>
<p class="primero">Primer párrafo con la clase ="primero"</p> 
<p class="segundo">Segundo párrafo con la clase ="segundo"</p> 
<p class="tercero">Tercer párrafo con la clase ="tercero"</p> 

<p>Elige una clase a destacar</p>
<input type = "text" name = "valor" value = "" id = "clase">

<button onclick = "myFunction()">Enviar</button>

</body>
</html>
```